# Real domain and range function to find all functions with nonzero x.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy $$ f(x)  + 3 f\left( \frac {x-1}{x} \right) = 7x $$
for all nonzero $x$.

My thoughts so far are to plug in $(x - 1)/x$ for $x,$ but it always comes out so complicated, so I don't really know where to go from there.

Comment: i did but it didn't really help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)  + 3 f\left( 1-\frac {1}{x} \right) = 7x$$
$x\to\frac{1}{1-x}$:
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+3f(x)=7\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)
$$
$x\to1-\frac{1}{x}$:
$$
f\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+3f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=7\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
Hence, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
f(x)+3 f\left( 1-\frac {1}{x} \right)+0 &= 7x\\
3f(x)+0+f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)&=7\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
0+f\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+3f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)&=7\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$
Solve for $f(x)$:
$$
f(x)=-\frac{3}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{x}{4}+\frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=\tfrac{1}{1-x}$ to get $f(\tfrac{1}{1-x}) = 7(\tfrac{1}{1-x})-3f(x).$

Substitute $x=1-\tfrac{1}{x}$ to get $f(1-\tfrac{1}{x}) = 7(1-\tfrac{1}{x})- 3f(\tfrac{1}{1-x}).$

So we have three equations to work with:
\begin{align}
f(x)+ 3f(1-\tfrac {1}{x})= 7x,\\ 
f(\tfrac{1}{1-x}) = 7(\tfrac{1}{1-x})-3f(x),\\
f(1-\tfrac{1}{x}) = 7(1-\tfrac{1}{x})- 3f(\tfrac{1}{1-x}).
\end{align}

Substituting the third equation into the first yields $$f(x)+ 3(7(1-\tfrac{1}{x})- 3f(\tfrac{1}{1-x}))= 7x,$$
which simplifies to :$$f(x)-9f(\tfrac{1}{1-x}) = 7x-21(1-\tfrac{1}{x}).$$

Then substitute in the second equation to yield $$f(x)-9(7(\tfrac{1}{1-x})-3f(x)) = 7x-21(1-\tfrac{1}{x}).$$

which expands and simplifies to $$28f(x)=7x-21+\tfrac{21}{x}+\tfrac{63}{1-x}.$$

Divide both sides by 28, put the right side over a common denominator, and multiply both the numerator and denominator on the right by $-1$ to yield
$$f(x) = \frac{x^3-4x^2-3x-3}{4x(x-1)}$$

for $x \ne 0,1.$

As the question asked for solutions to all nonzero x, we can substitute back into the original equation and find that $$f(x)= 7-3k$$
for $x=1.$

(Also note that $f(x) = k$ for $x=0$)